# Online shopping cart java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this code is not adding up at the end in "TOTAL COST".

Two classes:

ShoppingCartPrinter.java and ItemToPurchase.java

The result I keep getting are all 0's in "TOTAL COST".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

ShoppingCartPrinter.java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingCartPrinter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = 0;
  String productName;
  int productPrice = 0;
  int productQuantity = 0;
  int cartTotal = 0;

  ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
  ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();

  System.out.println("Item 1");
  System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
  productName = scnr.nextLine();                                         // Sets the variable productName for user input

  System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
  productPrice = scnr.nextInt();                                         // Set the variable productPrice for user input

  System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
  productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();                                      // Set the variable productQuantity for user user input
  System.out.println("");

  item1.setName(productName);
  item1.setPrice(productPrice);
  item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);

  System.out.println("Item 2");
  System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
  scnr.nextLine();
  productName = scnr.nextLine();                                         // Set the variable productName for user input

  System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
  productPrice = scnr.nextInt();                                         // Set the variable productPrice for user input

  System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
  productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();                                      // Set the variable productQuantity for user input
  System.out.println("");

  item2.setName(productName);
  item2.setPrice(productPrice);
  item2.setQuantity(productQuantity);

  cartTotal = (item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity()) + (item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity());

  System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
  System.out.println(item1.getName() + " " + item1.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item1.getPrice()  + " = $" + (item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity()));

  System.out.println(item2.getName() + " " + item2.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item2.getPrice()  + " = $" + (item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity()));
  System.out.println("");

  System.out.println("Total: $" + cartTotal);

  return;
   }
}
```

ItemToPurchase.java

```
public class ItemToPurchase {
   private String itemName;
   private int itemPrice;
   private int itemQuantity;

public ItemToPurchase() {
  itemName = "none";
  itemPrice = 0;
  itemQuantity = 0;
  return;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  itemName = name;
  return;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
   itemPrice = 0;
   return;
}

public void setQuantity (int quantity) {
   itemQuantity = 0;
   return;       
}

public String getName() {
  return itemName;
}

public int getPrice() {
  return itemPrice;
}

public int getQuantity() {
   return itemQuantity;
}

public void printItemPurchase() {
  System.out.println(itemQuantity + " " + itemName + " $" + itemPrice +  " = $" + (itemPrice * itemQuantity));
}
}
```

Comment: Add the code in your question and not as links.

Comment: `public void setPrice(int price) {
   itemPrice = 0; /* HERE you should probably use "price" */
   return;
} 
` I don't see why you are surprised by your 0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `setters`. You are assigning 0 (zero) to the items.

```
itemPrice = 0;
```

and

```
itemQuantity = 0;
```

This can be fixed by doing something like:

```
itemPrice = price;
```

and

```
itemQuantity = quantity;
```

Also, you do not need the `return` statements at the end of each method that has a `void` return type, especially in the `ItemToPurchase()` constructor. You can safely remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The zybooks assignment applies the setters automatically, it is not by choice. there is only certain parts of code that can be edited. I am currently working on this project and have been running into problems as well. Just wanted to clarify its not the coders fault they are set to 0

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete this lab and It was really difficult but here is the code that works.

for the shopping cart printer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
      public class ShoppingCartPrinter {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

         int i = 0;
         String itemName;
         int itemPrice = 0;
         int itemQuantity = 0;
         int cartTotal = 0;
         
         ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
         ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();

// Get item 1 details from user, create itemToPurchase object

         System.out.println("Item 1");

         System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
         itemName = scnr.nextLine();
         item1.setName(itemName);

         System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
         itemPrice = scnr.nextInt();
         item1.setPrice(itemPrice);

         System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");

         itemQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
         item1.setQuantity(itemQuantity);
         scnr.nextLine();

         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("Item 2");
         System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");

         itemName = scnr.nextLine();
         item2.setName(itemName);

         System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");

         itemPrice = scnr.nextInt();
         item2.setPrice(itemPrice);

         System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");

         itemQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
         item2.setQuantity(itemQuantity);

         System.out.println("");

         cartTotal = (item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity()) +
         (item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity());

         System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
         System.out.println(item1.getName() + " " + item1.getQuantity() +
         " @ $" + (item1.getPrice() + " = $" + item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity()));
         System.out.println(item2.getName() + " " + item2.getQuantity() +
         " @ $" + (item2.getPrice() + " = $" + item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity()));
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("Total: $" + cartTotal);

for the items to purchase:

public class ItemToPurchase {

      String itemName;
      int itemPrice;
      int itemQuantity;

public ItemToPurchase() {

      itemName = "none";
      itemPrice = 0;
      itemQuantity = 0;
}
public String getName() {

    return itemName;

}
public void setName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return itemPrice;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    if (price < 0) {
        itemPrice = 0;
    }
    else {
        itemPrice = price;
    }
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return itemQuantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    if (quantity < 0) {
        itemQuantity = 0;
    }
    else {
        itemQuantity = quantity;
    }
}
public void printItemPurchase() {
      System.out.println(itemQuantity + " " + itemName + " $" + itemPrice +
      " = $" + (itemPrice * itemQuantity));

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@skw is correct, the mutator methods should not be set to 0:

```
public void setPrice(int price) {
    itemPrice = price;
}

public void setQuantity (int quantity) {
    itemQuantity = quantity;
}
```

Also, note that the set method is void so you don't need a return statement in the end, just change the price of the variable and you are done!